# .htaccess migrator from apache 2.2 to apache 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, environment, request-uri

Im trying to migrate my .htaccess file from apache 2.2 to apache 2.4, but i'm having a hard time recreating these deny/allow rules.

```
#deny access to all files inside folders
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/.+\.[a-z]+$" deny

SetEnvIf Request_URI "(\.gitignore|\.htaccess)" deny

# set acces to public accessible files in main admin folder
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/admin/(index\.php|tmp)" allow

# set acces to public accessible files in module folders Admin and Site
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/modules/[^/]+/(site/([^/]+/)?|admin/)(css|js|plugins|images|files|cache|fonts)/" allow

# set acces to public accessible files in uploads folder
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/uploads" allow

SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(.*\.xml|.*\.pdf|.*\.js|.*\.htm|.*\.asp|.*\.html|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php|communicationlog\.png|sitemap-?([a-z]+)?\.xml\.?(gz)?$)" allow

Order deny,allow
Deny from env=deny
Allow from env=allow
```

These are the rules im currently struggling with. It seems very hard to recreate these with the   `<Require>`, `<RequireAll>` and `<RequireAny>` directives. Can anyone help us out?

I tried just adding these rule with a `<RequireAll>` and `<RequireAny>` directives, but these basically deny the entire site and does not reproduce the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having two variables `deny` and `allow`, I would have just one "allow" var, which is then unset (ie. `!allow`) as required, instead of setting `deny`. This "allow" variable should be set by default (inline with the `Order deny,allow` directive that *defaults* to `allow` if neither is set).

By having just one variable allows you to grant access with a single `Require` directive.

I would also call this variable something other than `allow`, to avoid any confusion with the `allow` directive. For the sake of this example I will call it `ALLOW_ACCESS` (convention dictates all uppercase).

So, the rules would then become (`SetEnvIf` directives are pretty much the same, except for the additional "initialisation" one and use of env var):

```
# Default is to allow access
SetEnvIf ^ ^ ALLOW_ACCESS

#deny access to all files inside folders
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/.+\.[a-z]+$" !ALLOW_ACCESS

SetEnvIf Request_URI "(\.gitignore|\.htaccess)" !ALLOW_ACCESS

# set acces to public accessible files in main admin folder
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/admin/(index\.php|tmp)" ALLOW_ACCESS

# set acces to public accessible files in module folders Admin and Site
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/modules/[^/]+/(site/([^/]+/)?|admin/)(css|js|plugins|images|files|cache|fonts)/" ALLOW_ACCESS

# set acces to public accessible files in uploads folder
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/uploads" ALLOW_ACCESS

SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(.*\.xml|.*\.pdf|.*\.js|.*\.htm|.*\.asp|.*\.html|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php|communicationlog\.png|sitemap-?([a-z]+)?\.xml\.?(gz)?$)" ALLOW_ACCESS

Require env ALLOW_ACCESS
```

Note that since there is now just one "variable" to grant access, the order of the directives is now significant. Although they already happened to be in the correct order.

If you have any other (deprecated) `Order`, `Allow` and `Deny` directives then they also need to be converted at the same time, to avoid any unexpected conflicts.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> #deny access to all files inside folders
> SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/.+\.[a-z]+$" !ALLOW_ACCESS
>
> SetEnvIf Request_URI "(\.gitignore|\.htaccess)" !ALLOW_ACCESS
> ```

It looks like these two directives could be combined:

> ```
> SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.[a-z]+$" !ALLOW_ACCESS
> ```

Which effectively blocks all dot-files (not just `.gitignore` and `.htaccess`), but that is usually desirable.

Comment: A simple and elegant solution, thank you so much!